# Double buffering and flicker in java.awt

Tags: java, image, applet, awt, flicker

I am working through the online Kilobolt tutorial for a (awt-based) java game and have a question related to double buffering and update()/paint() functions. I do not understand why in one case the image flickers while in the other case it does not. 
"Flickering" case:

```
// ... in init() somewhere: offscreen_gfx = offscreen_img.getGraphics();
// ...
// only paint() method overridden
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  offscreen_gfx.drawImage( robot, 100, 100, this);      
  g.drawImage( offscreen_img, 0, 0, this);
}
```

"Non-flickering" case:

```
// only update() method overridden
public void update(Graphics g) {
  offscreen_gfx.drawImage( robot, 100, 100, this);
  g.drawImage( offscreen_img, 0, 0, this);
}
```

It looks to me that the code is essentially identical, given default update() simply(?) calls paint(). Why is there the difference?

Comment: If I add `super.update(g)` in the second case, it becomes flickering.

Comment: If I recall, in AWT update is responsible for clearing the contents of the component, by filling it with the background color of the component, before calling paint. If you could override update to simply call your paint method and perform you double buffering there

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In part, I am confused by http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#awt_summary , namely by the following "_For most programs, all client paint code should be placed within the scope of the component's paint() method._"

Comment: Yep `paint` is the preferred method, but because you need to control the flickering, you need to override `update` and stop it from doing what it's doing (filling the background) or inert your double buffering at this level (creating a compatible image and using it's `Graphics` context to paint to instead of the supplied context)